# How to define a piecewise function in matlab?

Tags: matlab

I want to calculate the convolution sum of the continuous unit pulse with itself, but I don't know how I can define this function 
$$ \delta(t) = \begin{cases} 1, 0 \le t \lt 1 \\
0, otherwise \end{cases}$$
in Matlab.

Comment: Related question: [Piecewise function plot in Matlab](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/533221/piecewise-function-plot-in-matlab). Or are you asking about symbolic functions specifically?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the [rectangularPulse](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/symbolic/rectangularpulse.html) function.

Or you can define arbitrary piecewise functions in a number of ways, e.g.

ix=x<0

y(ix)=0

ix=x>=1

y(ix)=0

ix=0<=x&x<1

y(ix)=1

Comment: Ok, thanks this is what I was looking for, but is there anyway to define arbitrary piecewise functions?.

Comment: @DavidMartínez I have updated my answer.

Answer (score 1):

For symbolic math you can take advantage of [MuPAD](http://www.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/getting-started-with-mupad.html) within Matlab. See the documentation for [`piecewise`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/mupad_ref/piecewise.html). You can use this function to concisely produce the example in your question:

```
pw = evalin(symengine,'piecewise([t >= 0 and t < 1, 1],[Otherwise, 0])')
```

And you can evaluate it for vector inputs using [`subs`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/subs.html) like this:

```
subs(pw,'t',[1/2 1 0])
```

which returns

```
ans =

[ 1, 0, 1]
```

See the documentation for [`piecewise`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/mupad_ref/piecewise.html) for more examples of how to define piecewise functions. There are other ways to call MuPAD functions from Matlab – [see here](http://www.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/call-built-in-mupad-functions-from-the-matlab-command-window.html). Of course this method is not meant for performance, so you shouldn't rely on it being as fast as floating-point methods.

Answer (score 0):

Create a MATLAB function with the following code

```
function d = delta(t)
if t >= 1
  d = 0;
else if t < 0
  d = 0;
else
  d = 1;
end
end
```

And use **delta** for whatever reasons you want.