# Matlab, how do I change the default scatter plot size?

Tags: matlab

I am trying to do a approximation plot with Runge Kutta. In matlab, the discrete plot I use is "scatterplot".

Unfortunately because of so many data points, the data points get mashed in and forms a line almost.

Also each data point is a giant empty circle. I was wonder if it is possible to just plot dots.

Examples of what I am getting.

is it possible to make it more sparse and dotted points instead of void circles?
Thanks
[image][image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Piecewise function plot in Matlab](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/533221/piecewise-function-plot-in-matlab)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the Matlab documentation:

> `scatterplot(x,n,offset,plotstring)` is the same as the syntax above, except that `plotstring` determines the plotting symbol, line type, and color for the plot. `plotstring` is a string whose format and meaning are the same as in the plot function.

and for plotting dots with the plot function you can use `plot(A,B,'.')`  i.e. `'.'` is the `plotstring` you want.

For more information have a look [here](http://de.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/scatter.html?refresh=true)

**Example**

> theta = linspace(0,1,500);
>   x = exp(theta).*sin(100*theta);
>   y = exp(theta).*cos(100*theta);
>   figure
>   s = scatter(x,y,'.');
>   figure
>   t = scatter(x,y,'sr');

will output:
[image]

[image]

Comment: How do you know what plotstring symbols are available, I tried googling and found irrelevant links. I even tried custom symbols like the letter 'A'.

Comment: @Hawk have a look at the link given in the answer (scroll down)